# my for prints the whole word even if i'm indexing it with a counter

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, printing

My code:

```
for i in range(0, word_leght-1) :
        out=word[i]
        sys.stdout.write(out)
```

This cycle for some reason waits for all the word to be completed before printing it. What I want it to do is to show a letter at a time without a newline. 
Is there a way to do so? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think calling `sys.stdout.flush()` after `sys.stdout.write` should do the trick as it will flush the buffer holding the output.

Comment: That worked, thank you.